# Converting SQL query to MySql query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, crystal-reports

I've got this query that I'm trying to convert myself word for word:

```
SELECT "Job_Operation"."Work_Center",
       "Job_Operation"."Job_Operation",
       "Job_Operation_Time"."Work_Date",
       "Job_Operation"."Est_Total_Hrs"."Job_Operation_Time"."Act_Run_Hrs",
       "Job_Operation_Time"."Act_Setup_Hrs",
       "Job",
       "Job"."Description",
       "Job_Operation_Time"."Overtime_Hrs"."Job_Operation_Time"."Act_Setup_Hrs",
       "Job"."Job",
       "Job"."Description",
       "Job_Operation_Time"."Labor_Burden",
       "Job_Operation"."Est_Setup_Labor",
       "Job_Operation"."Est_Run_Labor",
       "Job_Operation"."Est_Labor_Burden"."Job_Operation"."Operation_Service"
FROM {oj("Job" "Job"
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "Job_Operation" "Job_Operation"
    ON "Job"."Job"="Job_Operation"."Job")
  LEFT OUT JOIN "Job_Operation_Time" "Job_Operation_Time"
    ON "Job_Operation"."Job_Operation"."Job_Operation"="Job_Operation_Time"."Job_Operation"}
```

And this is what I came up with for MySql:

```
SELECT Job_Operation.Work_Center,
       Job_Operation.Job_Operation,
       Job_Operation_Time.Work_Date,
       Job_Operation.Est_Total_Hrs.Job_Operation_Time.Act_Run_Hrs,
       Job_Operation_Time.Act_Setup_Hrs,
       Job,
       Job.Description,
       Job_Operation_Time.Overtime_Hrs.Job_Operation_Time.Act_Setup_Hrs,
       Job.Job,
       Job.Description,
       Job_Operation_Time.Labor_Burden,
       Job_Operation.Est_Setup_Labor,
       Job_Operation.Est_Run_Labor,
       Job_Operation.Est_Labor_Burden.Job_Operation.Operation_Service
FROM LEFT JOIN (Job LEFT JOIN Job_Operation ON Job.Job=Job_Operation.Job)
     LEFT JOIN Job_Operation_Time Job_Operation_Time
       ON Job_Operation.Job_Operation.Job_Operation=Job_Operation_Time.Job_Operation
```

But its clearly not working. Where am I going wrong? Is there an easy tool out there to help with this kind of thing? Upon further investigation I realized that this is a CRYSTAL REPORT QUERY as its not working on my SQL server either.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: You don't have a table name specified, you just have `FROM LEFT JOIN` ... needs to be `FROM <table> LEFT JOIN` ...

Comment: Your original query isn't valid SQL. The `FROM {oj("Jo ... }` is invalid and looks suspiciously like some ORM dialect.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Ahh oops this was grabbed from a Crystal Report, apologies. I thought it was SQL but its not even working there.

Comment: You should add some line breaks to your queries here to make them more readable.

Comment: @degenerate See my comment to a_horse_with_no_name, non the less, thats still not working.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Cannot call methods on int.  No idea what that means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a stab here:

```
SELECT "Job_Operation"."Work_Center"
    ,"Job_Operation"."Job_Operation"
    ,"Job_Operation_Time"."Work_Date"
    ,"Job_Operation"."Est_Total_Hrs"
    ,"Job_Operation_Time"."Act_Run_Hrs"
    ,"Job_Operation_Time"."Act_Setup_Hrs"
    ,"Job"."Description"
    ,"Job_Operation_Time"."Overtime_Hrs"
    ,"Job_Operation_Time"."Act_Setup_Hrs"
    ,"Job"."Job"
    ,"Job_Operation_Time"."Labor_Burden"
    ,"Job_Operation"."Est_Setup_Labor"
    ,"Job_Operation"."Est_Run_Labor"
    ,"Job_Operation"."Est_Labor_Burden"
    ,"Job_Operation"."Operation_Service"
FROM "Job" AS "Job"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "Job_Operation" AS "Job_Operation" ON "Job"."Job" = "Job_Operation"."Job"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "Job_Operation_Time" AS "Job_Operation_Time" ON "Job_Operation"."Job_Operation" = "Job_Operation_Time"."Job_Operation"
```

I eliminated the awkward "somewhere this is proprietary" syntax, fixed a couple of periods that should have been commas, changed `OUT` to `OUTER`, and provided `AS` statements for table aliasing. This should be ANSI-compliant now, hopefully this helps.

**EDIT**

Updated my answer to escape all reserved words by encasing things in quotation marks. Also eliminated the double-selection of `Job.Description`.

Comment: I'm getting this error,  Cannot call methods on int. when running mine and your query.

Comment: pretty sure that `Job` is a reserved word, so I've updated my answer to encase everything in backquotes (just in case something else is as well).

Comment: Getting incorrect syntax error, tried your suggestion as well but same thing.

Comment: then it is something outside of your query. have you tried just doing a `SELECT *` from each table individually, to ensure that the permissions are set appropriately?

Comment: Well SQL Server Management Studio is giving me a syntax error on all "`" even a simple Select * From `Job` gets a syntax error but when I take out the "`" it works. SELECT * has worked on all the tables.

Comment: Why are you querying in SQL Server Management Studio for MySQL? the backquotes wont work there ... let me change to convert to quotes.

Comment: Okay I on the last LEFT OUTER JOIN, I changed "ON Job_Operation.Job_Operation.Job_Opeartion = Job_Operation_Time.Job_Operation" to "ON Job_Operation.Job_Operation = Job_Operation_Time.Job_Operation"

Not sure if that would hurt my results but it seems to work.

Comment: Oh bloody hell I must have copied and pasted incorrectly, yes there should only be one alias. updated my answer as such. sorry about that.

Comment: Because I'm testing the query where the DB is located. I'm on Linux so the db has been linked using ODBC and accessing it through adminer, this modified query without the quotes worked now in Adminer.

Comment: While were here I might as well ask you. Do you know how I would add a parameter to check against Work_Date column, so only display results with a work_date from the last 90 days?